# Dundas Dashboards Charts

Tags: dundas

I am maintaining a product developed on Dundas Dashboards v 2.5. In one of the dashboards they are rendering data in Pie Charts and Bar Charts. For bar charts on the y axis the values appear as Million. I mean 6M , 8M. But in pie charts the value shows up as 6000000 for 6M.

Is there any setting in Bar Charts that displays data as 6M and 8M etc. One more thing to note is that they are using the same dataset to display the data. So, I am assuming that there is some setting at the chart level.

Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the bar chart in the dashboard designer.  In the property grid, drill into the "Y Axes" property, and from there into the "Scale" property.  At the bottom of the Scale properties, there is one property called "Label Format".  Copy this value, and paste it into the same property for the pie chart.

See here for more info: http://support.dundas.com/Dashboard3.Chart_Usage.ashx